# Beautifulsoup not extractig information from <script type="text/javascript">

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need a way to get informations from a web page. That info is stored in `<script>` tag and i can't find a way to extract it. Here is the last iteration of the code i used.

```
for link in urls:
    driver.get(link)
    #print(driver.title)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
    for a in soup.findAll(string=['script', "EM.", "productFullPrice"]):
        print (a)
        name=a.find(string=['EM.sef_name'])
        print(name);
```

print(a) and print(name) return nothing.

The source code i want to scrape looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var EM = EM || {};
        EM.CDN = 'link1';
        EM.something = value;
```

Comment: what value do you actually want from the above script tag? And is there an example url?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the text inside the tag you can't just pass 'EM' to the string tag because it is looking for a string that exactly matches 'EM'. That also means it won't match the `script` tag either and will only look for the string `script` inside the tag itself. To get the node you need to pass `script` as a node to the `findAll` function. If you look at the text value of what's between the script tag it looks like this `"\n        var EM = EM || {};\n        EM.CDN = 'link1';\n        EM.something = value; \n "`. So it won't find `EM` because `EM` isn't equal to that string I posted above. There are a couple ways you can go about this here is one I chose to help return values similar to what you posted:

```
import bs4
html_string = '''
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var EM = EM || {};
        EM.CDN = 'link1';
        EM.something = value; 
 </script>
'''
wanted_strings= string=["EM.", "productFullPrice"]
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_string, features="html.parser")
wanted=[]
test = soup.findAll('script')
for word in wanted_strings:
    for tag in test:
        if word in tag.text:
            wanted.append(tag)
wanted
```

which will then give you the script lines in a list like this with the tags that contain the strings you need

```
[<script type="text/javascript">
         var EM = EM || {};
         EM.CDN = 'link1';
         EM.something = value; 
  </script>]
```

Another way to do this is just look for the tag and then place each line of code in a list

```
import bs4
html_string = '''
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var EM = EM || {};
        EM.CDN = 'link1';
        EM.something = value; 
 </script>
'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_string, features="html.parser")
test = soup.findAll('script')
blah = [x.strip() for x in test[0].text.split('\n') if x.strip()]
blah
```

which gives you something like this that may be easier to search for what you need depending on your use case

```
['var EM = EM || {};', "EM.CDN = 'link1';", 'EM.something = value;']
```